# create a table with a procedure : error 1064

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I try to create a table with a procedure but I have an error 1064 at this line:
PRIMARY KEY (`Dates`)');

this is the code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(IN tname varchar(20))
BEGIN

SET @s = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `test`.',tname,'(
  `Dates` DATE NOT NULL,
  `ncl1104` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `ncl1204` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Dates`)');

PREPARE stm FROM @s;
EXECUTE stm;
END
```

to call the procedure:

```
CALL new_procedure ('`new_oil_table`');
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `SELECT @s` to see what the string came out looking like.

Comment: I dont see you are declaring `@s` anywhere

Comment: Oh, you're missing the closing `)` for the `CREATE TABLE ()` statement after `PRIMARY KEY (Dates)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `)` at the end. I have tried the same but in SQL Server though. See below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE new_procedure
@tname varchar(20)
as
BEGIN
declare @s varchar(200);
SET @s = 'CREATE TABLE '+@tname+'(
  Dates DATE NOT NULL,
  ncl1104 VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  ncl1204 VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Dates))';

select @s
exec (@s);
END
```

In your code the error is @ below

```
SET @s = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `test`.',tname,'(
  `Dates` DATE NOT NULL,
  `ncl1104` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `ncl1204` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Dates`)'); <-- Here ) outside quote
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this mistake made me crazy.